# Как погрузить девайс в спящий режим?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! Хочу сделать такую штуку: пользователь нажимает на кнопку выключения на устройстве и оно погружается в спящий режим (блокируется экран), то же самое хочу сделать у себя в приложении, но по нажатию на сенсорную кнопку. Как мне сделать это? Допускается использование Root прав, но нельзя делать приложение администратором устройства.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Допускается использование Root-прав.

Этим я и воспользовался - сымитировал нажатие кнопки power.
Делюсь кодом, авось кому-нибудь пригодится :)

---

```
            if (!utils.ExecuteCommand("input keyevent KEYCODE_POWER", true))
            {
                utils.toast("Ошибка! Проверьте наличие root-прав на вашем устройстве!", true);
                System.exit(0);
            }
```

---

```
protected boolean ExecuteCommand(String command, boolean asRoot)
{
    try
    {
        if (asRoot)
        {
            Process mSU = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(mSU.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes(command);
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            mSU.waitFor();
            Log("Command" + command + " was executed as root");
        }
        else
        {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            Log("Command" + command + " was executed as user");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log("Execute Command: " + ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Согласно: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627714/how-make-mobile-go-sleeping-programmatically это не возможно реализовать в полной мере без android.permission.DEVICE_POWER, которое дается только системным приложениям. Для этого нужно делать свою прошивку, в которой это приложение будет включено в качестве системного.

Можно попробовать модифицировать настройку SCREEON_OFF_TIMEOUT как показано тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114270/android-screen-timeout
Но если какой нибудь процесс на фоне держит WakeLock, то это не сработает.