# Возможно ли управлять одной активностью из другой?

Tags: android, java

Хочется написать бота для одной онлайн игры на андроид. Поэтому мне надо узнать возможно ли управлять и изменять состояние одного приложения из другого? Что бы бот можно было в игре разные кнопочки тыкать согласно своей логике.

Comment: с рутом, я думаю можно, только выглядеть это будет, как эмуляция нажатий на экран в определенных координатах...

Comment: В какаую сторону копать ? Эт мне свой эмулятор надо писать что бы запускал apk ?

Comment: Точно можно, если это будет активити на другом телефоне/планшете. Вот для затравки [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/company/papabubadiop/blog/215913/).

Comment: Есть несколько разных фрэймворков для тестирования приложений, которые эмулируют поведение пользователя. Можно их попробовать как-нибудь прикрутить. А вообще если в игре GUI на OpenGL, то не подойдет. 

http://robolectric.org

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте выполнять терминальную команду

```
input tap X Y
```

для симуляции нажатия. Возможно потребуется рут.
Вот, можете чуть-чуть подправить мой [код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/290079/java-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC), чтобы добиться результата.

Answer (score -1):

Для того,чтобы иметь доступ к активности, то достаточно создать статичную ссылку на активность, пример:
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
public static MainActivity link;

public OnCreate(Bundle b){
link=this;
}
...

тогда обратиться к этой активности из любого класса можно таким образом:
MainActivity.link.***; ,где звездочки-это нужный метод или переменная.

Comment: а расскажите, как можно создать статичную ссылку на активность из другого приложения? Пожалуйста, дочитайте вопрос до конца.